# Why is Snakemake introducing whitespaces in my path to submodules?

Tags: ubuntu, path, snakemake, wsl-2, f-string

I have a workflow with modules that uses `conda` and `singularity`.

### Problem

When I try to run the workflow with `snakemake -c 8 --use-conda --use-singularity` (Snakemake 7.32.4), I get the following error:

```bash
WorkflowError in file /home/user/src/project/workflow/Snakefile, line 33:
Failed to open source file /home/user/src/project/workflow/  workflows/ extract /  Snakefile
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/src/project/workflow/  workflows/ extract /  Snakefile '
  File "/home/user/src/project/workflow/Snakefile", line 33, in <module>
```

### Question

Why do I get this error, when

1. The f-strings for the `extract` module are correct, and
2. the file `../workflow/workflows/extract/Snakefile` *does* actually exist?

### Setup

I run the whole affair from within a Miniforge3 conda env on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS within WSL2.

```yaml
name: project
channels:
  - bioconda
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - snakemake=7.32.4
  - singularityce
```

The `Snakefile` in `../workflow/` includes the following relevant snippets:

```py
MODULES_ROOT = "workflows/"

EXTRACT = "extract"
MODULE_EXTRACT = f"{MODULES_ROOT}{EXTRACT}/"
module extract:
    snakefile:
        f"{MODULE_EXTRACT}Snakefile"
    config: config[EXTRACT]

use rule * from extract as extract_*
```

### What I tried (to no avail)

- `ls`d and `cat`d the Snakefiles and checked correctness of spelling
- Rewrote the f-strings
- Updated Snakemake from an older version to the one described above
- Removed and re-created the conda environment

Comment: Does your MWE above actually throw the error for you? It works, i.e. the path is correctly printed in the error message (without additional spaces) for me on `snakemake==7.32.4` without `--use-conda` and `--use-singularity` on WSL2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is related to the fstring!
Once I remove all the f string it works.

```
These are the environments I am using
(base) [hsher@tscc-11-15 oligoCLIP]$ python --version
Python 3.12.0
(base) [hsher@tscc-11-15 oligoCLIP]$ snakemake --version
7.32.4
```

Comment: see this issue https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/2480